# Difference between velocity potential and stream function?

Tags: theory

I am currenty reading Fundamentals of aerodynamics(sixth edition) Jhon Anderson and in sections 2.14, 2.15 was introduced stream function and velocity potential concepts. I understand that both of them describe velocity vector fields, but I cannot fully distinguish difference between them. What is the difference in geometrical interpretation, where one approach can be more suitable than another, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream function $\psi$ lines end up parallel to streamlines.  Whereas velocity potential $\phi$ lines are perpendicular to those.  In many ways they are opposites - but think of them as complimentary.

A more mathematical explanation (too mathy for Anderson) starts with the [Helmholtz Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) (aka the fundamental theorem of vector calculus).

Helmholtz's theorem says that any vector field that is sufficiently smooth and that dies off at infinity can be expressed as the sum of two parts.

$\vec{V}=\nabla\,\phi+\nabla\times\vec{\psi}$

The first part $\nabla\,\phi$ is irrotational.  I.e. the curl ($\nabla \times \nabla \phi$) will always be zero.  There is no $\phi$ that can make this not true.

The second part $\nabla\times\vec{\psi}$ is selenoidal.  I.e. the divergence  $\nabla \cdot \left(\nabla\times\vec{\psi}\right)$ will always be zero.  There is no $\psi$ that can make this not true.

When we think of this in terms of fluid dynamics, we apply Helmholtz's decomposition to the velocity field $\vec{V}$.  When we think about inviscid, incompressible flow, that is a flow that is both irrotational and selenoidal.

You probably recognize that an irrotational flow is one where the [vorticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity) is zero everywhere.  The conservation of mass for an incompressible flow is equivalent to stating that the vector field is [selenoidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoidal_vector_field) (we don't usually use this word in fluid dynamics).

So, both of the conditions that apply to each of the terms in the decomposition apply to the flow that we're interested in.

What is a vector decomposition anyway?  We're separating parts.  If we had a general vector field (one with both curl and divergence), then the HVD would break that field into two -- one that represents all the curl and the other that represents all the divergence.  In our world, we're going to want to use these as unknowns that we're going to want to solve for.

Note that $\phi$ is a scalar, even when $\vec{V}$ is 3D.  $\phi$ can be called the potential, the scalar potential, or the velocity potential.

However, $\vec{\psi}$ is a vector in 3D -- but it simplifies to a scalar when we're only interested in 2D problems.  $\vec{\psi}$ is called the vector potential.  In 2D fluids problems, $\psi$ is called the stream function.

When we're solving problems, we need unknowns and we need conditions or equations to apply them to.  We have two choices of approaches.

1. We choose to apply the continuity equation.  I.e. $\nabla \cdot \vec{V}=0$.  We immediately know that the second term in the HVD can not contribute to the divergence, and so we can drop that term.  This leaves us with

$\vec{V}=\nabla\,\phi$

Which means that $\phi$ is our unknown.  We proceed to study potential theory aerodynamics with the continuity equation and the velocity potential as our unknown.

2. We choose to apply the vorticity equation (irrotational flow).  I.e. $\nabla \times \vec{V}=\vec{0}$.  We immediately know that the first term in the HVD can not contribute to the curl, and so we can drop that term.  This leaves us with

$\vec{V}=\nabla\times\vec{\psi}$

Which means that $\vec{\psi}$ is our unknown.  We proceed to study aerodynamics with the vorticity equation and the vector potential as our unknown.

In 2D, approaches 1 and 2 are extremely similar and either can be used.

However, in 3D, our unknown in approach 1 ($\phi$) remains a scalar, where our unknown in approach 2 ($\vec{\phi}$) is now a vector (i.e. it has three components).

The vector nature of the second approach makes it substantially more cumbersome in practice.  Consequently, we seldom deal with the second approach after initially introducing it at this stage of teaching aerodynamics.

The first approach goes on to be one of the most important tools in aerodynamics.

Comment: I cannot get If in approach 2 we assume that flow is irrotational(curl V = 0) why V consist of ψ which describe rotational part of flow? In section 2.15 of book from irrotational equation (curl V = 0) was derived V =∇ϕ contrast to your V =∇×ψ, why?

Comment: The derivation shown in 2.15 is more like a derivation of the first term of HVD than it is my approach 2 (which is a conclusion from HVD).  I did not derive HVD at all.  Anderson tries to show that when $\phi$ is a scalar, then $\nabla \phi$ will be irrotational always.  I just flipped through the book.  Anderson never talks about the second term of the HVD, never uses the term HVD, and never talks about my approach 2.  So, from Anderson's point of view, $\psi$ is some other field that exists and generates streamlines.

Comment: Is it proper to say that ∇ϕ describes the irrotational part of the flow and ∇×ψ describes the incompressible part of the flow? If so, in approach 2, we assume that V is irrotational shouldn't we set ∇×ψ to 0(so far ψ contains vortex information) in this case?

Comment: @AlexGenesis I think you have it a bit backwards.  A general flow can be compressible and rotational (and can be described by HVD). In approach 1 Since $\nabla \phi$ is incapable of describing a rotational flow (its curl is always zero), but it is capable of describing a compressible flow.  We then apply the incompressible condition to solve the equations.  In approach 2, $\nabla \times \vec{\psi}$ is incpaable of describing a compressible flow (its divergence is always zero), but it is capable of describing a rotational flow.  We then apply the irrotational condition to solve the equations.